# wrong result in division operation of bignumber.js javascript library downloaded from jsfromhell?

Tags: javascript, numbers, division

I am using bignumber.js(http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber)

Following division operation giving me wrong result:

```
a=new BigNumber(100)
alert(a.divide(1))
```

gives the result **100.0981** instead of **100**

Does anyone has encountered this problem? 
If anyone has solved it please help me to solve it also?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using

> alert(a/1)

as there is the bug in the divide function of bignumber.js

Answer (score 0):

The JS code you link to has a bug in it.

Given how cryptically it has been written, it's difficult to say exactly where the problem is, or how to fix it.

Comment: thats what i had thought and seeking if someone has already worked on this bug or not.